# Can anyone identify this tool for me

Tags: tools, hand-tools

Hello I'm new here so not sure if this belongs here, if not please redirect me to the appropriate stack exchange.

Now for the question does anyone know what this tool (thing) is?

[image]
[image]
[image]

This has been bothering me for a long while so any help in identifying this would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I can’t quite tell if it is just the photo, but is that top half tapered?

Comment: @kponz It's the picture it's flat and rusted. Editted the post with a topside view.

Comment: how large is it? ... maybe it is a high school metal shop assignment

Comment: @jsotola Both parts are about ~15 centimeters in height and about 6 centimeters in width. Knowing my dad it must have some practical use or he wouldn't keep it around.

Comment: i think that it may be a nut cracker

Answer (score 3):

It's a floor jack height extender.

Wow! I really love all the comments. The ones I'm actually familiar with had knurling on the sides instead of the black, looks like abrasive, coating shown on this one. They came in three different sizes and the set included a jack with a hole in the lifting plate that one end of the height increaser would fit into and a flange that would fit over the top for more stability. We mostly used them for support when working under machinery that had been partially lifted as they were easy to operate in confined areas without that 12" handle that's on many other types of supports.

Do you have any other parts like I've described?

Comment: i don't think that it would be strong enough when extended past a certain point

Comment: I must admit googling that does result in some objects looking like my object but they're not exactly equal. I'm not entirely convinced this is the right answer yet, but I might accept this if nobody has a better idea.

Comment: I am not 100% convinced myself.  If I am correct there is a pointed bit on the bottom inside the cup.  Am I right @Scjnagtz - If so there must be a reason for it or it wouldn't be there.Is there any threaded metal on the bottom of the cup making it sit above the ground in the photo?  I am also curious about the extra metal above the black area of the screw top.  A striking part?

Comment: @ChrisRogers There is indeed a small pointed bit at the bottom of the cup, I had not noticed that yet. It is very small though